# Passing text file content to Form 2

Tags: c#, winforms

I need help. I have two fomrs. One form contains listBox with text files on disk but the second form must display content of the file selected from listBox from form 1. The listBox from Form1 and richTextBox from Form2 are public allready.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    Form2 form2;
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      string folder = @"D:\";
      string[] txtfiles = Directory.GetFiles(folder, "*.txt");
      listBox1.Items.AddRange(txtfiles);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      form2 = new Form2();
      form2.Show();
    }
  }
}
```

Form 2

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    Form1 form1;
    public Form2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("");
      //TODO
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a reference to Form1, I would pass the file name into the constructor of Form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public Form2(string fileName)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    textBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
  }
}
```

then in your calling method:

```
form2 = new Form2(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
form2.Show();
```

Comment: in Form2  Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox

Comment: @user3099201 My example would work with a RichTextBox, too.  I can't see your code that produced that error, so all I can suggest is to re-read the posted answer.

Comment: Yes. The code is workable. But when I click on item in Form1, it open Form 2, but RichTextBox is empty. For example, in text file I have "Hello world" writed. I wanna it would be displayed in Form2.

Comment: @user3099201 Again, I can't see what you are doing.  My posted code does what you want it to do.  I've even tested it.

Comment: OK. One moment I'll make some usefull things

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_SexZpsLyTgdXRfdXR6dEd2N1E/edit?usp=sharing   Sorry for Refresh method)

Comment: @user3099201 You can't make your own parameter on the TextChanged method like that: `private void richTextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e, string fileName)`.  You didn't even look at my code.  Try looking at it again.  Replace `textBox1` with `richTextBox1`.  You definitely don't want to be loading the text in the TextChanged event, it would stackoverflow.

Comment: It work! But what can I do if I wanna load a big text file? That's what I mean. textbox load small text.

Comment: Ok. I did the same thing with richtextBox. Work! Thanks a lot